# Radio button option in preferences - android

Tags: android, background, radio-button, preferences

How can I have some sort of dialog box with group of radio buttons in my preferences screen. Something like;

[image]

Each of the buttons will be associated to a colour, such as red, blue, green, black, yellow etc and I have methods for each of the colours. When a radio button is pressed, I want the relevant method to be called. For example, one of my method is;

```
public void red(){
.....
.....
}
```

When the radio button that is labeled red is pressed then I want the red() method to be called which then will change the background colour of the main activity to red.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you solved this or not. I'm answering it after 11 months just in case anyone needed this 
first in your `PreferenceScreen` xml file put this

```
           <ListPreference     
                  android:title="Choose a Background"
                  android:summary="Select your favorite color"
                  android:key="chosenColor"
                  android:defaultValue="Black"
                  android:entries="@array/colorArray"
                  android:entryValues="@array/colorArray" />
```

then in your `strings.xml` make a string array for your entries and values like this:

```
         <string-array name="colorArray">
               <item>Black</item>
               <item>Red</item>
               <item>Blue</item>
         </string-array>
```

**Note:** You can use same array for both entries and values or you can use different arrays one array for entries ant another one for values, I used one for simplicity.

then in your preference activity class do the following

after adding your `PreferenceScreen` xml file

```
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_actions);
```

use `OnPreferenceChangeListener` to handle changes in your list values like this:

```
    findPreference("chosenColor").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        String color = newValue.toString();
        switch (color){
            case "Black":
                // your method corresponding to Black goes here
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Chosen color is: " + newValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case "Red":
                // your method corresponding to Red goes here
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Chosen color is: " + newValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case "Blue":
                // your method corresponding to Blue goes here
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Chosen color is: " + newValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

and voila, that's it you got it working

and here are some screen shots from my device

[image: The list]

and this is the result when you choose any color from the list

[image]

All cases (one at a time)

[image: Selected colors handling]

further reading [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html).

I hope this help!

Regards

Comment: Shouldn't the string array for entries's values be placed at `res/values/array.xml` instead of `res/values/strings.xml`?